# Is there a dependency between Skype Bot ID, Microsoft App ID and Microsoft Azure Bot Service?

Tags: azure-bot-service, skype-bots

I am feeling a little bit lost with Microsoft.
https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol
Skype is telling me that I need a Bot ID (also known as Microsoft App ID).
At the same website is a link labeled with Microsoft App ID pointing to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Do I have to "Create a bot with the Azure Bot Service" so that I get a Microsoft App ID that works with Skype?

Or can I get a Microsoft App ID that is independent from Azure?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a bot that works with Skype, you need to have a [bot channels registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). If you already have a bot hosted elsewhere and you would like to use the Bot Service to connect it to channels such as Skype, Twilio, Messenger etc., you will need to register your bot with the Bot Service. A Bot Channels Registration bot service allows you to use Bot Service functionality. A registration bot lets you connect your bot to channels. You cannot get a Microsoft App ID that is independent from Azure.The Microsoft AppID is the same as the Bot ID that skype wants for the webchat bubble.